# Generic iterator/pointer initialization

Tags: c++, iterator, generic-programming

I have a C++ class `Finder` that stores a location in containers plus some additional data. Such containers have the type `std::string` but also `char *` or `MyString`. Say, the class looks like this (`Iterator<TContainer>::Type` is a trait / metafunction that returns the iterator type for a given container):

```
template <typename TContainer>
class Finder
{
public:
  typedef typename Iterator<TContainer>::Type TIterator;
  TIterator iterator;

  // Initialization of iterator: How to do it generically?

  // Finder {}                       // problem with pointers!
  // Finder() : iterator(0) {}       // problem with iterators!
};
```

The main problem now is how to initialize the iterator that can be a pointer or an iterator. If I only wanted to support my own containers then I could simply implement a constructor that takes `nullptr_t` following [the nullptr idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/nullptr). However, since I want to support pointers, my own iterators *and* STL iterators, I'm a bit out of depth here.

The best thing that I can imagine is to write a `getNil<>()` function, e.g. the code below. However, now at least three questions arise:

1. Is this the best way to achieve my aim?
2. How to determine whether a type is a STL iterator? I would probably need some `#if`s, and tailor code to each compiler/STL version to use.
3. Is it possible at all to get a **nil** iterator in the STL? Is the result of `x-y` in `std::vector<int> x, y; int x = x-y;` defined at all?

The code:

```
// Forward declaration.
template <typename T>
T getNil<T>();

template <typename TValue> TValue * getNil<TValue *>()
{ return NULL; }

template <typename TValue> TValue * const getNil<TValue * const>()
{ return NULL; }

template <> TValue * const getNil<MyIterator>()
{ return MyIterator(nullptr); }  // nullptr from above idiom

template <> TStlIterator
boost::enable_if<
    MagicallyDetermineIfIsStlIterator<TStlIterator>::value,
    TStlIterator>
getNil<TStlIterator>()
{ return MyIterator(nullptr); }  // nullptr from above idiom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Finder() : iterator() { }
```

Should do the trick. Not providing an argument for a member in the initialization list will call the default constructor on a type that has one, and will zero-initialize POD types including pointers (and it will fail if the type has no default constructor, but that seems unlikely given your scenario).

Comment: Great! For the record, this is documented in 8.5.5 in N3242.